# Reverse proxy apache :80 -> django runserver :8000 (interno)

Tags: django, apache, proxy

Comento el problema que tengo:

Tuve que montar un servidor django con apache y wsgi en un servidor VPS, lamentablemente descubrimos que no hay compatibilidad del módulo con cpanel.

Como opción b provisoria se me ocurrió arrancar el proceso de runserver para el servidor de desarrollo django en el puerto 8000 (0.0.0.0:8000) y con apache crear un reverse proxy que me redireccionara todas las peticiones que entran en el dominio.com por el puerto 80 al puerto 8000 de forma interna, es decir:

(dominio.com)apache:80 -> (django)runserver:8000

De esta forma puedo servir de forma pública el sitio web que estaba construído en django sin problemas, al menos no del sitio:

```
<VirtualHost 200.73.113.21:80>

        ServerName mueblesvaldes.com

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8000/

</VirtualHost>
```

EL PROBLEMA: Como todas las peticiones del dominio.com se me redireccionan al proceso interno del runserver 0.0.0.0:8000, pierdo todos los accesos a cualquier otra url, como por ej dominio.com/cpanel, dominio.com/webmail, y etc, ya que caen en la redirección también.

Yo no tengo muchos conocimientos de apache pero algo he echo, y creo que si ustedes me ayudan podría llegar a solucionarlo.

Por alguna razón actualmente los subdominios no están funcionando y tenía una idea con respecto a esto, pero tuve que pensar en otra: hacer la redirección del reverse proxy sólo si el subdirectorio por el que entra la petición es "/s", es decir "dominio.com/s/", pero que al llegar la petición al runserver de django llegue en su forma original y no con la del "/s" del subdirectorio, para que así django sepa encontrar la url en su manejador de URLS.. pero no logro conseguirlo.

Alguna idea que me ayude a resolver esto??